# joomla 3, переменные и их переопределение, com_content

Tags: joomla, cms, joomla3

В какой переменной хранится информация какая страница назначена главной и можно ли ее изменить не внося изменения в БД.

Comment: Все, что меняется в админке, то находится в бд. Php может переписывать свои файлы, конечно, но это было бы на камильфо. Единственные пользовательские данные, которые хранятся как переменные  - в файле config, там, насколько я помню, есть инфа о домене, но не о главной странице. Вообще не советую вручную менять такие вещи в бд.

Comment: @larrymacbarry, можете тогда предложить вариант, как можно переключать `главную страницу` "налету" ? Без админки и не затрагивая БД. Уже много перерыл информации, но результат пока нулевой.

Comment: А что вам надо сделать и зачем? Чтобы сервак с помощью php мог менять главную страницу?

Comment: @larrymacbarry, скорее не главную страницу даже, а главное меню (просто они ведь связаны). Пока разбираюсь с вопросом - переосмысливаю. У меня получается, что новости и некоторые модули смотрят на главное меню. Меню, как понимаете не одно, отображается в зависимости от url (пример:  http://site.ru/ , http://site.ru/1-menu, http://site.ru/2-menu). Домен один. Чтоб все отображалось корректно, надо переключать главное меню.

Comment: почему вам не сделать или все на отдельных страницах site.ru, site.ru/1-menu, site.ru/2-menu, или менять грид на фронтенде в зависимости от запроса "site.ru?menu=2"

Comment: @larrymacbarry, я бы изначально все сделал иначе, но работаю с тем что есть и править и переписывать все - нельзя. Необходимо исправить отображение некоторых моментов, которые зависят от главного меню. Все что выводится через К2 - проблем не имеет.